# How to stop a local database from launching the online website?

Tags: 8, redirection

I'm a designer and new to Drupal. been studying for a couple of months creating sites for personal learning. I started working in a company that had a Drupal 7 website. I studied, learned it and change it.

This year a Design Studio redesign our image and made a Drupal 8 site. They gave me full access and I downloaded a copy of the files and the database and proceed to install it locally to test and change it.

I use Acquia DevDesktop and import the site with new database and the I went into phpMyAdmin and import the database. Then I load the site and it immediately launch the real online site.

I thought there was something in the files and check them extensively with the little knowledge that I have. I found nothing.

To check if the "reroute" was in the files I made a fresh install of Drupal 8 and after setting it up as a new site I went into phpMyAdmin and import the database. Without changing any file I launched the site and again it went in to the real online site. So I thing the "reroute" is in the database.

I called the Design Studio and the responsible for the site was a Designer. He created the site online and didn't managed it locally. He try to help me but was unable to pinpoint the reason for the local installation to go to the real online site. He couldn't set up the site locally either.

How to change this "reroute" so I can set up my site locally?

Comment: Is the "Rules" module installed?

Comment: No "Rules" module in the folder or in the "Extend" section of UI.

Comment: There are probably more than half a dozen ways to redirect a site, and hundreds of places that could be done within the code/database. I don't think we'll be able to guess which one of those is used in your site from here. A developer would work it out in about 5 minutes, but realistically they'd need access to the environment to do so

Comment: Could be a number of things, for starters, the .htaccess file.

Comment: If you're able to name the most common ways i'l be happy to research and look for it.

Comment: With regard with the .htaccess file, that's the reason I try the new installation, so I could be sure no file was responsible as all files where new.
Nonetheless in the files from the website in the .htacces file in the main folder I found two lines mentioning the website:
(I'm not sure how to write two lines of code as it seems I'm not allowed)

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.org*`

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.org/$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: I compared the .htacces file with one a clean install and remove the code mention above. Basically return the file to its original.

The local site continue rerouting to the real online site.